# gcc compiler warning flags missing

Tags: gcc

I wanted to use some of the warning flags listed on https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html. However it appears I can´t use all of them. For example `-Wpessimizing-move` is not recognised by gcc for me (always generates a error because this option does not exist). This problem exists for quite a few of the flags.
I use gcc from the fedora repository
Thats my version output:

```
Es werden eingebaute Spezifikationen verwendet.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Ziel: x86_64-redhat-linux
Konfiguriert mit: ../configure --enable-bootstrap --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++,ada,go,lto --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --enable-multilib --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-gcc-major-version-only --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --with-isl --enable-libmpx --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-gnu-indirect-function --enable-cet --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread-Modell: posix
gcc-Version 8.3.1 20190223 (Red Hat 8.3.1-2) (GCC)
```

The same error occurs both with gcc and g++.
What could be the reason for this behaviour? And how to fix it?

Comment: Hopefully `gcc` doesn't _crash_ as you say, but just generates an error. Correct?

Comment: Yes should have been more specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation clearly says this is for C++ only:

> -Wpessimizing-move (only for C++)

So `g++` will accept it, but not `gcc`.

For documentation one can check the corresponding entry for [llvm -Wpessimizin-move](https://reviews.llvm.org/D7633).

Here is a copy, though:

> This warning will catch:
>
> - Using std::move in a return where the moved object is a local variable
> - Using std::move on a pr-value object
>
> ```
> struct A {}  
> A test() {  
>     A a = std::move(A());  // warn since A() is a pr-value  
>     return std::move(a);   // warn since a is a local variable  
> }
> ```

Comment: no I get exactly the same error when runnign it with g++

Comment: @maxbachmann that probably means you have a version which does not yet support that command line. I don't see it on Ubuntu 18.04 yet. It's not unlikely available on the tip of the gcc's suite.

Comment: I will upgrade to Fedora 30 which has gcc-9 and test it there ;)

Comment: Oh just saw it gets introduced in gcc 9 in the release informations at https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-9/changes.html